# Power window doesn't work from master switch, only goes down from local switch

Tags: power-windows

The master switch won't move the rear passenger window at all. All other windows work.

The local switch on the rear passenger window moves it down only. All other windows work.

Furthermore, the problem has gone away a couple times: we've been able to put the window up using the local switch after trying a lot, banging and reassembling the door. But the problem quickly came back.

Any suggestions what the issue is or how to find it? I'm thinking there must be a poor connection or broken wire *somewhere*? The vehicle is a 2003 Honda CRV.

Comment: Press down or up on the master switch while pressing down or up at the same time on the rear switch, if it goes down or up, one of the switches is bad, more than likely the master switch. If one of the switches has a bad neutral position it will prevent either switch from moving the window up or down, using both switches at the same time will verify this.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! More than likely the master switch is bad. These had a tendency for rain water (or whatever liquid) to get splashed on them, which caused them to go bad. Just replaced the one in my '03 Civic, which I believe might be the exact same switch.